# Activites Overview slow to appear

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview, animations, 19.10

When I press the super key or click the "Activities" entry in the menu bar, it takes a good 2-3 seconds for the Activities Overview (with search and thumbnails of open windows) to appear. Now, this only happens when I have lots of windows open, and of course the obvious solution is to not have so much open at once, but that's not how I work :P I actually don't use those window thumbnails at all, and only use the super shortcut to search and launch apps. Is there any way to speed things up, maybe by disabling the thumbnails somehow? Note I have tried the gnome tweaks to speed up animations, and the slow behaviour persists regardless of animation speed, so I'm sure it's about computing those thumbnails and now the actual transition animation.

I'm on a 2018 Razer Blade 15 with an i7 and 16GB of ram. I use a menu item to monitor system resources and the slowness happens even when RAM usage is <50%.

Comment: I'm on a 2015 Razer Blade with an i7 and 16GB of ram. I use a menu item to monitor system resources and the slowness happens even when RAM usage is <50%

Comment: Oops, not that it makes a difference but it's a 2018 Blade.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented with opening a ton of windows and loading the activity overview.

I have found that for me anyways, the number of windows is the factor that matters the most. When I spam Ctrl+alt+T to open tons of empty terminals, the time it takes to load activity overview increases significantly.

If you are also having lots of windows open and they are all terminal windows, try to use tabs instead of windows. The same goes for Web browsers, text editors, etc.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, though I already purely use super-tab/super-` to switch between apps; my use of activity overview is purely for the search bar. I should probably just try to find an alternative app launcher and bind that to super.